# Why do propagators have singularities at the Fermi surface?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, solid-state-physics, crystals, singularities, propagator

Consider the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}\frac{1}{i\omega - E(K)}\frac{1}{i\omega - E(K')}$$

At the Fermi level $K=K_f$, $E(K)=0$ and supposedly we have a singularity in the propagator. I don't get this. I compute the integral and its value is finite:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}\frac{1}{i\omega}\frac{1}{i\omega - E(K')} = \frac{1}{2E(K')}$$

So one propagator has its singularity while the other doesn't, but the product of the two is finite. I think I'm missing something fundamental about this. Could anyone elaborate on propagators, their singularities and why this result is finite?